# Inserting Multiple rows as Parameters - Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have two tables, Invoice, and Items.

I am using Stored Procedure for inserting Data into invoice Table. The Invoice should have multiple items. Following is the stored procedure I am using to insert a row into Invoice Table.

```
@InvoiceDate date,
@Vno int,
@Vdate date,
@ClientId int,
@ItemId int,
@Discount bigint,
@InvoiceID int,
@CreditAmount bigint,
@CreditDate date,
@CreditType varchar(15),
@Quantity int,
@InvoiceQuantity int

AS
Insert Invoice 
        ([Invoice Date], [Voucher No], [Voucher Date], ClientID, ItemId, Discount, Quantity) 
        VALUES (@InvoiceDate, @Vno, @Vdate, @ClientID, @ItemId, @Discount, @InvoiceQuantity)
        SET @InvoiceID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()            

Insert Credits 
               (CreditAmount,        CreditDate,    ClientID,    [Invoice Id],    [Credit Type]) 
VALUES (@CreditAmount, @CreditDate, @ClientID, @InvoiceID,    @CreditType)

update Items set ItemQuantity = ItemQuantity - @Quantity where ItemID = @ItemId
```

The problem is that I cannot insert multiple Items in my Table (I am using a parameter '@ItemId' for that purpose). I cannot use more than one parameter for 'ItemId' As as the number of items varies and User will select items on runtime.

I am using SQL Server Database. This stored procedure is being used in a Windows Form Application in VB.Net.

Comment: Look into table-valued parameters. You can't send multiple INT values through a single INT parameter.

Comment: or just call adding the items in a loop from the client program, even though there are several round trips involved.